# Python / Pandas - Drop columns that start with string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
id    2013 Profits   2001 Revenues    1999 Assets...
31    xxxx           xxxx             xxxx
...
```

I want to drop the columns that do not start with '201' (I only want to keep the data 2010 and forward).

How can I do that?

Comment: isn't this question just the inverse of one of your previous questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820359/python-pandas-select-columns-that-start-with-some-string?

Comment: @EdChum you are correct, I think I'm going nuts already. Sorry about that. I wanted to make another question but I counfused everything. Do you think that I should I delete this one?

Comment: Up to you but I'm not sure how much value there is in this question, I've not close voted or down voted for that matter. Others may well feel different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**`pd.DataFrame.filter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```
df.filter(like='201')

   2013 Profits
id             
31         xxxx
```

---

As pointed out by @StevenLaan using `like` will include some columns that have the pattern string somewhere else in the columns name.  We can ensure that we only get columns that begin with the pattern string by using `regex` instead.

```
df.filter(regex='^201')

   2013 Profits
id             
31         xxxx
```

Comment: This also includes columns that for any other reason contain 201. use a regex to make sure that is only at the start `df.filter(regex='^201')`

Comment: @StevenLaan you are absolutely correct.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 6):

This will ensure that only columns starting with 201 will be kept.

```
df[[c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('201')]]
```

The same can be achieved with

```
df.filter(regex='^201')
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way:

```
In [16]: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('^201')]
Out[16]:
  2013 Profits
0         xxxx
```