# Drop multiple columns that end with certain string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns using the suffix '_o'. Is there a way to drop all the columns that has '_o' in the end of its label?

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844382/python-pandas-drop-columns-that-start-with-string) I've seen a way to drop the columns that start with something using the filter function. But how to drop the ones that end with something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Pandonic**

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith('_o')]

df = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.endswith('_o')]]
```

**List comprehensions**

```
df = df[[x for x in df if not x.endswith('_o')]]

df = df.drop([x for x in df if x.endswith('_o')], 1)
```

Comment: List comprehensions are not correct, it should be df.columns not df. E.g., [x for x in df.columns...]

Comment: @Yasmin, No, it's fine.. `for x in df` loops through the column names of a dataframe.. test it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

To use `df.filter()` properly here you could use it with a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'a_o': [2, 3], 'o_b': [4, 5]})

>>> df.filter(regex=r'.*(?<!_o)$')
   a  o_b
0  1    4
1  2    5
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by re-assigning the dataframe with only the needed columns

```
df = df.iloc[:, [not o.endswith('_o') for o in df.columns]]
```